# HTML resource not getting constrained in servlets

Tags: html, jsp, servlets, resources

first of all some details: I configured security as below in web.xml
view plaincopy to clipboardprint?

```
<login-config>  
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>  
    <form-login-config>  
        <form-login-page>/formLoginPage.html</form-login-page>  
        <form-error-page>/formErrorPage.html</form-error-page>  
    </form-login-config>  
</login-config>  
<security-constraint>  
    <web-resource-collection>  
        <web-resource-name>MyBeerApp</web-resource-name>  
        <url-pattern>/web/form.html</url-pattern>  
        <url-pattern>/SelectBeer.do</url-pattern>         
        <http-method>POST</http-method>  
        <http-method>GET</http-method>  
    </web-resource-collection>  
    <auth-constraint>  
        <role-name>member</role-name>  
    </auth-constraint>  
    <user-data-constraint>  
        <!--transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee-->  
    </user-data-constraint>  
</security-constraint>  
<security-role>  
    <role-name>admin</role-name>  
</security-role>  
<security-role>  
    <role-name>member</role-name>  
</security-role>  
<security-role>  
    <role-name>guest</role-name>  
</security-role>
```

in tomcat-user.xml as below:
view plaincopy to clipboardprint?

```
  <role rolename="member"/>  
  <role rolename="guest"/>  
  <user username="vgarg2" password="tomcat" roles="member,guest" />  
  <user username="vgarg3" password="tomcat" roles="guest" />
```

file are location as below:
view plaincopy to clipboardprint?

```
<TOMCAT_HOME>\Beer-v1\index.html  
<TOMCAT_HOME>\Beer-v1\web\form.html  
<TOMCAT_HOME>\Beer-v1\WEB-INF\web.xml  
<TOMCAT_HOME>\Beer-v1\WEB-INF\classes\...
```

contents of form.html:

view plaincopy to clipboardprint?

```
<html>  
<body>  
<h1 align="center">Beer Selection Page</h1>  
<form method="POST" action="../SelectBeer.do">  
Select Beer Characteristics  
Color : <select name="color1" size="1">  
            <option value="light1">Light</option>  
            <option value="amber1">Amber</option>  
            <option value="brown1">Brown</option>  
            <option value="dark1">Dark</option>  
        </select>  
    <br/>  
Can sizes:  
<input type="checkbox" name="sizes" value="12oz">12 oz</input>    
<input type="checkbox" name="sizes" value="24oz">24 oz</input>  
<input type="checkbox" name="sizes" value="36oz">36 oz</input>  
    <br/>  
    <center>  
        <input type="submit"/>  
    </center>  
</form>  
</body>  
<html>
```

Now my problem is that the request going to "http://localhost:8080/Beer-v1/web/form.html" is not getting constrained.
when I submit the request from /web/form.html to "http://localhost:8080/Beer-v1/SelectBeer.do" it checks for the authentication and asks for id/password info.

If i disable the security constraints the app works fine.

what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think issue here is that the response for `http://localhost:8080/Beer-v1/web/form.html` is being served from cache.

If you require authentication for static pages, you should be sending cache control header saying the caching entities not to cache the response. For this you should be sending the following headers along with the response:

- Cache-Control: no-cache,no-store
- Pragma : no-cache

**NOTE:** Without applying the headers above, if you refresh the page using F5, you should see that the authentication will work.

**I would suggest to have all the pages which requires authentication as JSP's.**

Comment: Bingo Ramesh :) It worked. 
But now I have another question since the request is going to "/web/form.html" directly and there is no servlet involved in between how can I set the headers you mentioned in the response?

Comment: Check if the server supports adding header to the static pages. Else, write a custom filter for static pages.